# Um valor possívelmente perigoso Request.Form foi detectado no cliente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

estou com problema no momento que envio esse tipo de digitação no campo input: `&&&&%$&#_(@)(#_!**@#)24 R87R XDHNSIFN 89Q7201784` ocorre o Erro de perigoso Resquest.Form.

Messagem de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TesteInputValidation.Models;

namespace TesteInputValidation.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Cartao t)
        {
            var teste = t;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TesteInputValidation.Models
{
    public class Cartao
    {
        public string CartaoBeneficiario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model TesteInputValidation.Models.Cartao
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "frmFiltro", @class = "smart-form"}))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartaoBeneficiario, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNumeroCartao" })

    <footer>
        <button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wait-process">Enviar</button>
    </footer>
    }


</div>
```

Se eu tirar a validação vai tirar todas as validações do Data Annotation?

Existe uma forma de tratar esse erro corretamente?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Decore seu método com o atributo `ValidateInput`

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult index()
{
   return view();
}
```

Talvez você precise disso em seu Web.Config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Comment: Mas não existe alguma forma de não precisa desativar o Validate Input? alguma tipo de Script ou função no Razor que decodifica o html ?